# Logging Response body in nginx without installing any other tool like Lua etc

Tags: nginx

I am working on a project which uses nginx as web server, nginx by default logs request body. I need to log response body data in json format (response is itself in json format) but I cannot use any supporting tool like Lua etc. My client is not permitting it.
I did it using openresty but that is not approved.
Is it possible to achieve in simple nginx installation?
If yes, then please help me.